# Magento ver. 1.9.2.4 - Shopping cart rule issue

Tags: catalog-price-rules, magento1.9.2.4

I am trying to set up a shopping cart rules to work like this:
if specific SKU inside the cart and quantity ordered between 20 and 59 (inclusive) - the customer will get a different price/free product etc.

As you can see in the image I got 1st part setup >=20, but when I try to add an additional line for product sub-selection to be less or equal to 59, shopping cart rule page auto-refreshes and I am back to the admin dashboard. This happens if I try to create a rule from scratch or amend an existing one. Previously everything was working fine, just a couple of days ago I tried to set this up and noticed this issue.

[image]